# Поисковый модуль на php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли бесплатные поисковые модули, учитывающие морфологию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть  к примеру [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)
, это поисковый движок он запускается в виде отдельного демона и индексирует базу, дальше посылаете поисковые запросы непосредственно к сфинксу.  Есть расширение для php [расширение](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sphinx.php)